# Using Geocoder to retrieve address based on Latitude and Longitude causes lag. Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map activity which also has an EditText on top of it and I want to show the changing address in that EditText whenever there's a drag on the map. I am currently using Geocoder class to retrieve address based on the coordinates provided by the map. But this way is causing a lot of lag in the fluent dragging motion of the map. Is there a better way to retrieve address or a more efficient way to use Geocoder class? Right now, I have implemented the getAddress() method inside the OnCameraChangeListener event of my map. Here is the code.

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                double latitude=mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude;
                double longitude=mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude;
                String _Location="";
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
                        _Location = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                EditText addressTxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_address_txt);
                addressTxt.setText(_Location);
            }
        });
```

I have seen another app implemented where the address searched was at the end of the map drag and there was no lag in the map's motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Geocoder$getFromLocation()` is a blocking call, which means it will freeze the UI thread till the api returns the address. The only solution is to run this call on a background thread.

There are two ways you can achieve this:

1. Use Google recommended way - Using an `Intent Service`. You can find the details on how to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html). Personally, I feel this is overkill and very complicated.
2. Use an `AsyncTask`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13551405/2625032) to get a general idea and implement according to your needs.

Also, if you are using Rx, you can start a new observable from the geocoder and observe on a different thread and subscribe on the main thread.

**UPDATE:** I pulled this code from one of my old projects, see if it helps.

```
AsyncGeocoderObject.java // object to pass to asynctask

public class AsyncGeocoderObject {

    public Location location; // location to get address from
    Geocoder geocoder; // the geocoder
    TextView textView; // textview to update text

    public AsyncGeocoderObject(Geocoder geocoder, Location location, TextView textView) {
        this.geocoder = geocoder;
        this.location = location;
        this.textView = textView;
    }
}
```

The AsyncTask implementation

```
public class AsyncGeocoder extends AsyncTask<AsyncGeocoderObject, Void, List<Address>> {

private TextView textView;

@Override
protected List<Address> doInBackground(AsyncGeocoderObject... asyncGeocoderObjects) {
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    AsyncGeocoderObject asyncGeocoderObject = asyncGeocoderObjects[0];
    textView = asyncGeocoderObject.textView;
    try {
        addresses = asyncGeocoderObject.geocoder.getFromLocation(asyncGeocoderObject.location.getLatitude(),
                asyncGeocoderObject.location.getLongitude(), 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return addresses;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {
    Log.v("onPostExecute", "location: " + addresses);
    String address;
    if (addresses != null)
        address = addresses.get(0).getLocality() + ", " + addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    else address = "Service unavailable.";
    textView.setText(address);
}
}
```

Calling the method when location changes:

```
new AsyncGeocoder().execute(new AsyncGeocoderObject(
                new Geocoder(this),
                location,
                locationTV
        ));
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE 2:**

Notes on how to immplement the above:

1. Create new class `AsyncGeocoderObject` and copy the contents
2. Create another class (can be a sub-class within the activity or in a different java file) `AsyncGeocoder` and copy the contents.
3. Now, say you want to get the users location in `MainActivity` and display the address in a textview, say `locationTV`. After instantiating the textview, create a new object of `AsyncGeocoder` and pass in the parameters. eg:

   ```
   // in onCreate()
   new AsyncGeocoder().execute(new AsyncGeocoderObject(
           new Geocoder(this), // the geocoder object to get address
           location, // location object, 
           locationTV // the textview to set address on
   ));
   ```

   Also, if you dont have a location object, create on using the latitude and longitude you have. [See this post for how to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983865/making-a-location-object-in-android-with-latitude-and-longitude-values)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Appreciate the help. But can you please guide me a little where to put that code? In the activity where i need to get the address? Or do i make a new java class?

Comment: @RehanYousaf added some more details. see if they help

Comment: I wanted to use the LatLng so I changed the parameters in the code you provided accordingly. Thank you! Its working now.

Comment: glad i could help! :)